# How to delete td without any id

Tags: javascript

[image]

Hello i want to remove "Have you served in the military ?" and "No" if Answer is "No" but when it will "Yes" than it should show.

Whatever i have tried but it's not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  for(i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i]); i++){
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Have you served in the military') > -1){
    document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: You can find <span> with id and then find its parent <td> and delete it.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine -> **https://jsfiddle.net/4g7rxm43/**

Answer (score 0):

You can get all td elements like you already did and than get the span elements inside them:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('TD');
for (var i = 0, l = tds.length; i != l; ++i) {
    var spans = tds[i].getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
    for (var j = 0, l2 = spans.length; j != l2; ++j) {
        var span = spans[j];
        if ((span.textContent = span.innerText).indexOf('Have you served in the military') != -1) {
            span.style.display = 'none';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** OP wants to only delete the span if there is a td with the content "No" (also delete the td element)

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('TD');
var tdsLength = tds.length;

var answerNoFound = false;
for (var i = 0; i != tdsLength; ++i) {
    var td = tds[i];
    if ((td.textContent = td.innerText) == 'No') {
        td.style.display = 'none';
        answerNoFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (answerNoFound)
    for (var i = 0; i != tdsLength; ++i) {
        var spanFound = false;
        var spans = tds[i].getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
        for (var j = 0, l = spans.length; j != l; ++j) {
            var span = spans[j];
            if ((span.textContent = span.innerText).indexOf('Have you served in the military') != -1) {
                span.style.display = 'none';
                spanFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (spanFound)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I have to remove both question and answer if answer is "No".
"No" is also in td but don't have any id after that i have to remove both

Comment: In the uploaded image is only a td element with the content "Yes" but i will edit my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could use child of the element or just do a find replace or even hide and show.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an application form and `document` probably has more spans, some outside the `td` elements, so you don't get correct selection of `spans` versus `td`.

So when you are comparing `span` content, it is most likely not the `span` that is inside your looped `td`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
      for(i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i]); i++){
        if(a.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML.indexOf('Have you served in the military') > -1){
          a.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    })();
</script>
```

I changed the if statement to select `span` inside your looped `td`, that should do it.